# When should we choose lateinit for an object ? Is it bad practice to make the binding as non-optional and lateinit?

Tags: android, binding, kotlin-lateinit, lateinit

I was declared a binding object in a fragment as `lateinit var binding: EditInsuranceDialogBinding` but a colleague said "This is a bad practice and *Binding* object should be *Optional* . "

So in the declaration will be instead like this: `var binding: EditInsuranceDialogBinding? = null`, initialised in the `onCreateContentView` and make it `null` in the `onDestroyView`

I want to know what is the best to choose the type of Binding (optional or not)? and does **lateinit** cost a lot in the compiler  and memory ? When we should **NOT** choose **lateinit** and when we should use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but a colleague said "This is a bad practice and Binding object should be Optional . "

It is possible that your colleague really meant that the binding object should be wrapped in `Optional`.

> I want to know what is the best to choose the type of Binding (optional or not)?

`lateinit var` is not evil. However, it is not ideal for all circumstances.

In this case, a binding object has a specific lifecycle, and we need to stop using it after `onDestroyView()`. If you declare the property as:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: EditInsuranceDialogBinding
```

...then you have no way of setting it to something after `onDestroyView()` that says "we do not have a valid binding". It is easy to wind up having code in a fragment that runs after `onDestroyView()`, and that code needs to know that it is not safe to use the binding. There is no way to create an `EditInsuranceDialogBinding` instance that represents the "not safe to use the binding" state.

The alternative that you chose is reasonable:

```kotlin
private var binding: EditInsuranceDialogBinding? = null
```

...where you set `binding` to `null` in `onDestroyView()`.

You could also go with:

```kotlin
private var binding: Optional<EditInsuranceDialogBinding> = Optional.empty()
```

...where you set `binding` back to `Optional.empty()` in `onDestroyView()`. There are also custom binding delegates, such as [this one](https://github.com/Zhuinden/fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt), that you could use.

> and does lateinit cost a lot in the compiler and memory ?

No.

> When we should NOT choose lateinit and when we should use it?

I try to only use `lateinit` when I am *very* certain that I will initialize it before use.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! Very pleased to have an answer from Mr Murphy.

Answer (score 1):

This one is not bad approach. We use lateinit when we guarantee the initialization before using it. lateinit doesn't allocate the memory until it is initialized.

It is initialized only once. Next time when you use it, you get the value from memory where it is used for the first time.